# how to install tensorflow on python3.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

I tried instruction like this but failed:

```
pip3 install -t /projects/****/users/****/python/3.7.0 --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.10.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

the error message is just cannot find the url. If I change version like cp37 to cp36 which will also failed since the version of python is 3.7.

If I just use the instruction:

```
pip3 install -t /projects/****/users/****/python/3.7.0  tensorflow
```

it will have such an error message:

```
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

So how exactly to install tensorflow on python3.7?

I tried the instructions in the other post but none of them works.

Comment: Did you happen to copy/paste your post title into Google?!

Comment: I tried same instruction like this: pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow. I still get the second error. Idk why.

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow does not support Python 3.7 yet (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022).

Use Python 3.6.