# ModuleNotFoundError in importing and working with keras/tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to start working on `keras` and `tensorflow` but I cannot figure out how to properly set them up and I keep getting errors in my `jupyter` notebook.

From searching for solutions online, I can tell that it's likely that my folders are misplaced and I cannot tell where I am downloading my files/packages.

All I'm trying to do is begin following udemy classes and to start messing around with `keras/tensorflow`, but I keep getting these errors everytime I try importing on `jupyter` notebook.

I'm on a *Windows OS*, and I suspect that the problem is due to a misplacement of either `Python37` or `Anaconda`, but I'm not sure how to begin solving it as everything I found online isn't working.

Any idea how as to what I'm doing wrong and how could I solve this problem?

[new error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgZwf.png)

[new error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi7cZ.png)

Comment: Did you install tensorflow? Please describe the problem and your environment, your current question is mostly about what you think the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I installed tensorflow by going to the Python directory on cmd and using `pip install tensorflow`.
My problem is that I cannot understand what I did wrong such that when I open Jupyter Notebook and attempt to import the packages, I get a ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: Did you install keras in the same way? The problem is usually that one package is installed in a different python interpreter because of a users' mistake.

Comment: Yes, I installed keras the same way, following instructions on [this webpage](http://inmachineswetrust.com/posts/deep-learning-setup/#cell2)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue once. When you start Jupyter notepad, by default it uses default anaconda environment. But if you want to switch to different environments you can use ipykernel.

```
source activate myenv
pip install --upgrade ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name your_conda_env --display-name "Python (myenv)"
```

Now when you start the jupyter you will see a list of environments(E.g Python (tensorflow-env)).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what keras.modules is... Do you mean keras.models?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

also Dense is from keras.layers so,

```
from keras.layers import Dense
```

Comment: woops, yes but even when I corrected it, I still get an error saying "no module named tensorflow" when im not even attempting to import tensorflow

Comment: Last I checked python37 doesn't support tensorflow. I would suggest you install python3.6 and then try again.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52655087/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-python3-7